# svg file and animation for all browser

Tags: css, animation, svg

I have svg file, which i need to animate, i didn know how to animate polygon inside this file so i decide to use CSS3 animation intead, but not all browser display it right, i mean for firefox and safari there is no animation, why?

This is svg file code: (plus_animation.svg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="104.5px"
 height="104px" viewBox="0 0 104.5 104" enable-background="new 0 0 104.5 104" xml:space="preserve">

<style type="text/css" >
  <![CDATA[

  @-webkit-keyframes pulse_animationW {
      0% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
      20% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.9); }
      40% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.7); }
      50% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.5); }
      60% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.7); }
      80% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.9); }
      100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
  }
  @-moz-keyframes pulse_animationM {
      0% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
      20% { -moz-transform: scale(0.9); }
      40% { -moz-transform: scale(0.7); }
      50% { -moz-transform: scale(0.5); }
      60% { -moz-transform: scale(0.7); }
      80% { -moz-transform: scale(0.9); }
      100% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
  }
  @-moz-keyframes pulse_animationMS {
      0% { -ms-transform: scale(1); }
      20% { -ms-transform: scale(0.9); }
      40% { -ms-transform: scale(0.7); }
      50% { -ms-transform: scale(0.5); }
      60% { -ms-transform: scale(0.7); }
      80% { -ms-transform: scale(0.9); }
      100% { -ms-transform: scale(1); }
  }
  @keyframes pulse_animation {
      0% { transform: scale(1); }
      20% { transform: scale(0.9); }
      40% { transform: scale(0.7); }
      50% { transform: scale(0.5); }
      60% { transform: scale(0.7); }
      80% { transform: scale(0.9); }
      100% { transform: scale(1); }
  }


    #topPlus{
        -webkit-animation-name: 'pulse_animationW';
          -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
          -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
          -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

        -moz-animation-name: 'pulse_animationM';
          -moz-animation-duration: 1000ms;
          -moz-transform-origin:50% 50%;
          -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;

        -ms-animation-name: 'pulse_animationMS';
          -ms-animation-duration: 1000ms;
          -ms-transform-origin:50% 50%;
          -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;

        animation-name: 'pulse_animation';
          animation-duration: 1000ms;
          transform-origin:50% 50%;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-timing-function: linear;

    }

    .botPlus{
        -webkit-animation-name: 'pulse_animationW';
          -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms;
          -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
          -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

        -moz-animation-name: 'pulse_animationM';
          -moz-animation-duration: 500ms;
          -moz-transform-origin:50% 50%;
          -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;

        -ms-animation-name: 'pulse_animationMS';
          -ms-animation-duration: 500ms;
          -ms-transform-origin:50% 50%;
          -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;

        animation-name: 'pulse_animation';
          animation-duration: 500ms;
          transform-origin:50% 50%;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
    }

    #midPlus{
        -webkit-animation-name: 'pulse_animationW';
          -webkit-animation-duration: 2000ms;
          -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
          -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

        -moz-animation-name: 'pulse_animationM';
          -moz-animation-duration:2000ms;
          -moz-transform-origin:50% 50%;
          -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;

        -ms-animation-name: 'pulse_animationMS';
          -ms-animation-duration: 2000ms;
          -ms-transform-origin:50% 50%;
          -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;

        animation-name: 'pulse_animation';
          animation-duration: 2000ms;
          transform-origin:50% 50%;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
    }

  ]]>
</style>


<g id="Warstwa_2" display="none">

    <rect x="-2637.5" y="-1982" display="inline" fill="#1D1D1B" stroke="#1D1D1B" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="6919" height="3576"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Warstwa_1">
 <g>
    <polygon id="midPlus" fill="#FFFFFF" points="56,48.5 56,2.5 49,2.5 49,48.5 3,48.5 3,55.5 49,55.5 49,101.5 56,101.5 56,55.5 102,55.5 
        102,48.5        "/>
    <rect class="botPlus"  x="3.086" y="82.952" fill="#FFFFFF" width="32.817" height="3.834"/>
    <rect class="botPlus" x="17.578" y="68.462" fill="#FFFFFF" width="3.834" height="32.815"/>
    <polygon id="topPlus" fill="#FFFFFF" points="102,17.5 87,17.5 87,2.5 83,2.5 83,17.5 69,17.5 69,21.5 83,21.5 83,35.5 87,35.5 87,21.5 
        102,21.5"/>

        <rect x="3.332" y="3.06" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.996" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="97.971" height="97.973"/>

        <rect x="3.332" y="3.06" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.996" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="97.971" height="97.973"/>

        <rect x="19.495" y="19.223" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.996" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="65.646" height="65.646"/>
    <rect x="2.833" y="2.561" fill="none" width="98.968" height="98.97"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

This is code in html page:

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2 text-center logoSVG">
    <img src="~/Content/img/technology_partners/benefits/plus.svg" alt="SVG">
    <p class="benefit-description">@Model.Benefit_1Text</p>
</div>
```

this is jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#benefits-div .logoSVG img').hover(function () {
    var split = $(this).attr("src").split(".svg");
    $(this).attr("src", split[0] + "_animation.svg");
}, function () {
    var split = $(this).attr("src").split("_animation.svg");
    $(this).attr("src", split[0] + ".svg");
});

});
```

Comment: Firefox has only supported transform-origin with percentage units for a couple of days now. It's in the nightlies if you want to try it, otherwise you'll need to avoid that and use some other units.

Comment: but still it not resolved the problem even if I delete transform-origin animation doesnt move

Comment: but i dont know how to load there svg file to show code inside it

Comment: i've just edit the topic

Comment: Firefox does not support CSS animation in images currently. I've been working on that off and on recently but I haven't fixed it yet. It does support SMIL animation.

Comment: To be clear this is because you're including the SVG via an `<img>` element. If you used and `<object>` or `<iframe>` instead, firefox would work.